# MySql error while updating an attribute in join table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, join

I have this schema

product.rb:

```
has_many :families_products  
has_many :families, :through => :families_products
```

family.rb:

```
has_many :families_products  
has_many :products, :through => :families_products
```

families_product.rb:

```
belongs_to :product  
belongs_to :family
```

and in `families_product` table i have an attribute called `price`, when i trying to update it after creation it throws an error.

```
1.9.3p0 :027 > family_product = FamiliesProduct.first
  FamiliesProduct Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `families_products`.* FROM `families_products`         LIMIT 1
 => #<FamiliesProduct family_id: 1, product_id: 1, created_at: "2012-09-10 12:31:54",     updated_at: "2012-09-10 12:31:54", points: nil> 
1.9.3p0 :028 > family_product.points = 2
 => 2 
1.9.3p0 :029 > family_product.save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.7ms)  UPDATE `families_products` SET `points` = 2, `updated_at` = '2012-09-10     12:53:05' WHERE `families_products`.`` IS NULL
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'families_products.' 
in 'where clause': UPDATE `families_products` SET `points` = 2, 
`updated_at` = '2012-09-10     12:53:05' WHERE `families_products`.`` IS NULL
```

I see that the generated query has an error, so any clue?

Comment: you created family_product object does not have id column. What u made it as a primary key for FamilyProduct model

Comment: yea i think in this, but join table shouldn't have a primary key i guess. Is there another solution except that one?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your "family.rb" at least (and possibly "product.rb:") are misconfigured. Did you define foreign key relationships? How is the system meant to guess how to link the tables?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are supposed to use the join tables model like this.
Try this:

```
 @family = Family.first #or some other family
 families_product = @family.families_products.where({:product_id => Product.first.id})
 families_product.points = 2
 families_product.save
```

Comment: I need to update the attribute after creation not in the creation process.

Comment: :)
I'm not asking how to do this :)
if you run this query in my env you will get the error i wrote above.

Comment: can you post your migration files?